# I am making async calls on every input change and then setting state with response. But state is not set with latest call's data

Tags: reactjs

I have an input box which should show list of countries based on data entered. The search should happen immediately as soon as data is entered(there should not be any delay). I am changing state of the component as soon as I get the response. But, the problem is response of api calls are not in order.If I type fast, the state is not getting updated with value of latest api's call, instead it is getting updated with previous(or whichever response is received in last) call's data.

I tried using AbortController so that when new call is made previous call is aborted. But, it is not working in IE.(and also not sure if this is good solution)

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    if (this.controller) {
      this.controller.abort(); // how to avoid this abortion of call.
    }
    if (value) {
        this.fetchData(value);
    } else {
        this.setState({
        data: []
        });
    }
    this.setState({ searchText: value });
}

fetchData = (value) => {

    this.controller = new AbortController();
    this.signal = this.controller.signal;

    fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + value, {
        method: 'get',
        signal: this.signal
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.slice(0, 5) }))
    .catch(err => {
        if (err.code === DOMException.ABORT_ERR) {
          console.log('Request canceled.')
        }
    });
}
```

```
Showing only first five values in the array.
Input: ame
Expected output:
American Samoa
Cameroon
Suriname
United States of America
Virgin Islands (U.S.)

Actual Output:(This output is coming when I remove the code which aborts the previous call.)
Afghanistan
Åland Islands
Albania
Algeria
American Samoa
```

Comment: seems you are creating a new controller every time `fetchData` is called, have you tried moving the creation of the controller to outside the functions?

Comment: Hi Doug, this code is working as per the expectations. I want to get rid of 'AbortController' as it is not supported by IE. Or is there any better solution?

Comment: you can find some [polyfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) for this feature with a quick Google Search. I won't suggest any specific one as I have never used them. You should also consider debouncing the API call so you don't fire one request for each key the user presses--instead you wait until a couple milliseconds have passed since the user stopped typing before you call the API.

Comment: the requirement is to call API on every keystroke without any dealy.

Comment: it seems that field is dealing with countries so your dataset is not too big. You should consider fetching ALL countries and storing them in memory(state). Your approach seems over-engineered, and unnecessarily slow. If you fetch all countries the user won't have to wait while typing and you can also get rid of the `AbortController` logic.